# predicate that uses slot assignment but using a list

Tags: prolog

```
day_schedule([2, 1, 2, 3, 0], [ta(y, 4), ta(h, 7), ta(r, 8), ta(s, 8)],
RemTAs,Assignment).
RemTAs = [ta(y, 1), ta(h, 5), ta(r, 5), ta(s, 8)]
Assignment = [[r, y], [y], [r, h], [r, h, y], []]
```

i should do this predicate and i can use the slot assignment predicate .

```
slot_assignment(3, [ta(y, 4), ta(h, 7), ta(r, 8), ta(s, 8)],
RemTAs,Assignment).
RemTAs = [ta(s, 7), ta(y, 3), ta(h, 6), ta(r, 8)]
Assignment = [s, y, h]

day_schedule([],TAs,RemTAs,X).
day_schedule([H|T],TAs,RemTAs,Assignment):-
   slot_assignment(H,TAs,RemTAs,Asignment),
   append(Asignment,[],X),
   day_schedule(T,TAs,RemTAs1,X).
```

this is my code but its not working

Comment: Please continue to reformat your question. In its current form, it will otherwise be closed.